# Exception caught: Should only call onDetach when the widget is attached to the browser's document

Tags: gwt

I am getting this exception in gwt:

> Exception caught: Should only call onDetach when the widget is attached to the browser's document

I have got multiple tabs (Eg A, B, C). Currently I am in tab B.
I will do some operations under content panel of tab B.
Contents of Tab B gets changed during operations.
Then, When I want to have default contents of Tab B, I click on Tab B,
and I am getting above exception.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Can you provide some actual code to show what you're doing?

Comment: Are you implementing or overriding onDetach() in any of your widgets?

Comment: No, I am not overriding onDetach().